# Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded with tree map

Tags: java, hibernate, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I keep getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` while loading rows from a Hibernate query.

I've tried increasing the memory a few times and it just continues to happen. I noticed in my logs that it appears to be pointing to a method where I'm using a `TreeMap`. I'm wondering if I'm using this incorrectly causing the out of memory issues.

```
public List<Item> getProducts() {
    List<ProductListing> productListings = session.createCriteria(ProductListing.class)
    .createAlias("productConfiguration", "productConfiguration")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("productConfiguration.category", category))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("active", true))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("purchased", true)).list();

    Map<String, Item> items = new TreeMap<>();

    productListings.stream().forEach((productListing) -> {
        Item item = productListing.getItem();
        items.put(item.getName(), item);
    });

    return new ArrayList<>(items.values());
}
```

- Is it safe to pass the values into the arraylist?
- Do I need to set the arraylist size?

I'm just wondering if I'm doing something terribly wrong. It looks correct, but the memory exceptions say otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I call this "loading the world" - the name `getProducts()` (with no args) is a bit of a code smell - as you're not restricting the result set size, and for all we know your `Item` objects could be large with lots of eagerly-loaded dependencies (not to mention all the backing Hibernate objects on the heap).

Another big problem is that you're expensively adding your dehydrated entities to a `TreeMap`, calling `hashCode()` and potentially `equals()`, only to throw away the keys and copy the values into a newly-allocated `ArrayList`.

Leaving aside the lack of pre-sizing of the `ArrayList` (correct, this is not ideal, though it should merely be slow), why the `TreeMap` stage? If there is aggregation you need to do, why not get the database to do that much more efficiently (e.g. via a `GROUP BY name`) and using an index, rather than pulling it all into a map for much slower re-processing? At the very least, by getting only unique `Item`s back, you could skip the map stage and copy straight into your list (there are even lighter-weight possibilities too, depending on your needs).

I strongly suggest testing with a proper Profiler. Specifically, it may help you determine the effect of eager-loading on heap size. Potentially just turning that off may make the problem much more manageable.

However, you also need to consider your code's clients: who actually needs **all** of those `Item`s? Most likely nobody.

Comment: Thank you, I redesigned everything and moved it into a query. Much better, problem resolved.